# How to load data into a modal from another component in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 4. I have 2 components, they are customer-list and customer-detail.

customer-list displays a list of customers. In this component,

- When clicking "Create customer", customer-detail popup will show and user can create new customer.
- When clicking the link of customer id, customer-detail popup will show and load customer info into this popup, and user can update this customer.

In customer-detail component, how to know when "create customer" is clicked, when customer id is clicked so that I can create or update customer correctly?

In customer-detail component, how to get customer id from customer-list component when user clicks customer id?

Thank you very much.

Here are my codes. Please take a look.

[image]

click create customer
[image]

click customer id
[image]

app.component.html

```html
<header>   
</header>
<main>
    <div class="main-content">
        <h3 class="page-heading">Customers</h3>
        <customer-list></customer-list>
    </div>
    <customer-detail></customer-detail>
</main>
```

customer-list.component.html

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customer-detail"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create customer</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form class="form-inline pull-right">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchTerm" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" placeholder="Search customer">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSearchClicked()"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Reference</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Middle Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let customer of customers">
            <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customer-detail" >{{ customer.id }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ customer.reference }}</td>
            <td>{{ customer.lastName }}</td>
            <td>{{ customer.middleName }}</td>
            <td>{{ customer.firstName }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

customer-list.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Customer } from './customer';
import { CustomerService } from './customer.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'customer-list',
    templateUrl: './customer-list.component.html',
    providers: [CustomerService]
})
export class CustomerListComponent {
    public customers: Customer[] = [];
    public searchTerm: string;

    constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) {       
    }

    onSearchClicked(): void {
        this.customerService.searchSimilarCustomers(this.searchTerm)
            .subscribe(customers => {
                this.customers = customers;
            });
    }
}
```

customer-detail.component.html

```html
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="customer-detail">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Create PL customer</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" [(ngModel)]="lastName" placeholder="Last name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="middleName">Middle name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="middleName" [(ngModel)]="middleName" placeholder="Midddle name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="firstName">First name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="firstName" placeholder="Last name">
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                </div>                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveCustomer()" data-dismiss="modal">Create</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

customer-detail.component.ts

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UUID } from 'angular2-uuid';

import { CustomerResource } from './customer';
import { ResourceData } from './customer';
import { CustomerService } from './customer.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'customer-detail',
    templateUrl: './customer-detail.component.html',
    providers: [CustomerService]
})
export class CustomerDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    modalTitle: string;    
    customerId: string;
    reference: string;
    lastName: string;
    middleName: string;
    firstName: string;
    
    constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) {        
    }

    ngOnInit() {        
    }

    registerCustomer() {
        let customerId = UUID.UUID();
        this.saveCustomer(customerId);
    }

    editCustomer() {
        this.saveCustomer(this.customerId);
    }

    saveCustomer(customerId: string) {
        let customerResource = this.mapToCustomerResource(customerId);
        this.customerService.registerCustomer(customerResource);
    }

    private mapToCustomerResource(id: string): CustomerResource {
        return {            
   //map customer
        };
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use the id of your user to navigate to his detail page.
To do so, you need something like this in your HTML :

```
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let customer of customers">
            <td><a [routerLink]="['/', { outlets: { popup: 'customer-detail/'+ customer.id + '/edit'} }]" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#customer-detail" >{{ customer.id }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ customer.reference }}</td>
            <td>{{ customer.lastName }}</td>
            <td>{{ customer.middleName }}</td>
            <td>{{ customer.firstName }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Then in your customer.route.ts :

```
export const customerDialogRoute: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customer-new',
    component: CustomerDetailComponent,
    outlet: 'popup'
  },
  {
    path: 'customer-detail/:id/edit',
    component: CustomerDetailComponent,
    outlet: 'popup'
  }
];
```

As you see from the code above, you can use the same component for create and update. In your CustomerDetailComponent you then get the param from the current route, and if the id exists, you get all the info of your customer and update it. If the id deosn't exist the you'll be in the case you have to create a new customer.

In the HTML, you only have to user *ngIf :

```
<h4 class="modal-title" *ngIf="!customer.id">
    Create a new customer
</h4>
<h4 class="modal-title" *ngIf="customer.id">
    Update customer
</h4>
```

Comment: I cannot use route because the dialog in the same page of customer-list component. You can see the app.component.html